# Monotouch dialog- Multiple textfield in single element?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, monotouch.dialog

I am using Monotouch dialog with Mvvmcross. My requirement is to have multiple textfield in single element/cell. But in Entryelement we have only one value property which has by default two way binding. Rest of the property are with only one way binding.

I have also tried with UIViewElement but same thing I can bind only one way. UI will update based on changes of ViewModel. But if something user will enter into textfield then how to fire ValueChange for it is challenge for me.

It would be good if somebody can point out rough steps to achieve it.

Comment: Your question does not make a lot of sense. You need to get someone to proof read your question and clearly cut out what your problem is. What have you tried?

Comment: Corrected minor mistake. First paragraph and even title indicates problem. End of first paragraph and second paragraph indicates what I tried and found problem,